# UIImagePickerController takePicture crashes

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I have been trying to find out what is causing this crash.
My main view controller has some code like this to start camera picker.

```
    pickerControl = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerControl.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    pickerControl.allowsEditing = NO;
    pickerControl.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    pickerControl.showsCameraControls = NO;
    pickerControl.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    pickerControl.delegate = self;
    overlay.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerControl animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The overlay is a view with a few buttons at the bottom. one of them is calling back to take picture.. and the call back will call takePicture like below..

```
    [pickerControl takePicture];
```

I dont know what is causing it, but it crashes immediately after calling takePicture. It doesn't happen all the time.. but it crashes more often.

Please help to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Do you have Exception breakpoints enabled? Please post a crash log.

Comment: http://www.rsaunders.co.uk/2013/06/add-exception-breakpoint.html

Comment: Hi sorry for not giving any exception details. Actually I just submitted my App to app Store built on iOS 6. After that only I tried to test if anything is broken in iOS 7 (by upgrading iOS 7 on my phone and deploying my app as an ad-hoc deployment through iTunes)
I cannot get my crash log because xcode 4.6 doesn't see my phone since it is already upgraded to iOS 7
Is there any other way to debug?

Comment: @travoux i have a problem with UIImagePickerController in iOS 7 beta 2, the takePicture method stopped working. You need to install xCode 5 Developer Preview to debug on iOs 7. what iOs 7 you use (beta 1 or beta 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about beta software that's accessible only after consenting to a non-disclosure agreement. So I'm going to ignore the iOS 7 aspect of the question.

As to getting a crash log, if you already know which method call is crashing then you're not going to get much out of it. But what you can do is use C's [`signal`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/) to install exception handlers for the various exceptions you want to trace.

Upon receiving such an exception, use [`[NSThread callStackSymbols]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/callStackSymbols) to get an array of call stack symbols — a backtrace in effect. You can then hastily write that to disk and, next run, read it back and notify yourself of it accordingly. Services like [Crashlytics](http://www.crashlytics.com) accumulate them and post them to a server. You could just open an `MFMailComposer` and send them to yourself as an attachment.

Using the Crashlytics SDK or a similar product directly would allow you to get live, traced crash reports regardless of whether the build has yet been submitted to Apple and without requiring Xcode to do any parsing.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to collect the crash log as advised!